# pi4j cant seem to get value for serial

Tags: raspbian, java, gps

I am working wit `GPS` and `Pi4J`. I am working with gps from adafuith and USB to TTL cable. But when I try to open serial it seem to give me a error. 
I can see the gps when I type in

```
ls /dev | grep USB
```

the error I get is where the line is

```
result=serirequired: int
```

the error message

```
found:    void
al.open(comPort, 4800);
```

[working for this tutorial](https://stephenjam.es/wp/raspberry-pi-rfid-reader-with-java-and-pi4j-part-1/)

my code

```
String comPort = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
serial.addListener(new SerialDataListener() {
    @Override
    public void dataReceived(SerialDataEvent event) {
        System.out.print("We received some data!");
    }            
});

//result=serial.open(comPort,2400);
int result=serial.open(comPort, 4800);
if ( result == -1 ) {
    System.out.println("Failed to open COM port!");
    return;
} else {
    System.out.println("COM port opened!");
}
try {
     // - Sleep for 20 seconds, (in ms)
    Thread.sleep(20000);

    // - Close port
    serial.close();
    System.out.println("COM port closed.");
} catch ( Exception ex ) {
    // - I am intentionally ignoring any exception.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

serial.open(comPort, 4800) doesn't return a value.
the signature of serial.open(...) is

void serial.open(String device, int baudrate);

try this:

serial.open(comPort, 4800);